# I am trying to code a 8-bit,4x1 multiplexer and I have seen some where that I can use a parameter to do so. Is there any other way to do it?

Tags: system-verilog

I am trying to code a 8-bit,4x1 multiplexer and I have seen somewhere that I can use a parameter to do so. Is there any other way to do it?

```
module multiplier (a,b,c,d,select,y);
parameter size =8;
input [7:0] a,b,c,d;//input
input [1:0] select;//2-bit select
output [7:0] y;// output
reg [7:0] select;
always @ (a or b or c or d or select)
case (select) //case select
          0: y=a;
          1: y=b;
          2: y=c;
          3: y=d;
default : y ='bx ;
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged this as SystemVerilog:

```
 module multiplier #(parameter size=8) (
             input [size-1:0] a,b,c,d,
             input [1:0] select,
             output logic [size-1:0] y);

    always_comb
    case (select) //case select
              0: y=a;
              1: y=b;
              2: y=c;
              3: y=d;
    default : y ='x ;
    endmodule
```